# Hibernate Criteria equivalent for IN clause in Subqueries?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

I would like to translate a query like this one:

```
FROM Entity_1 obj
WHERE obj IN (FROM Entity2) OR 
      obj IN (FROM Entity3)
```

To hibernate Criteria form, and the official [documentation of Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) is not enough because it doesn't say how to apply the `IN` statement.

Any hint?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The criteria API does not have a provision to add another query as a restriction.. i think what @Niroshan Abayakoon was trying to say is that you need to execute the queries for the `IN` clause seperatly & add the result to the `Restrictions.in()` condition.

```
List<?> entity2Data=//get data from either a query or criteria
List<?> entity3Data=//get data from either a query or criteria
Criteria c = // obtain criteria from session
// basically creates an OR condition chain
Disjunction orConditions = Restrctions.disjunction();
orConditions.add(Restrictions.in("obj", entity2Data));
orConditions.add(Restrictions.in("obj", entity3Data));
c.add(orConditions);
```

this would get hibernate to consider the list within the `IN` clause.

Its always better to fallback to HQL in situations like this.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still don't understand that "createCriteria(null)", why the null parameter? when do I query the Entity1? why the second createCriteria is independent from the first? i need to do obtain a single list at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Still problem, because `Restrictions.in(String, String)` expects a **propertyName** as first parameter (and I suppose you are trying to pass Entity2.class or "Entity", neither of them would work).

Comment: here `Entity2 and Entity3` are considered to be a string containing the name of the property.. i've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at my initial HQL query, there are not such "someProperty" nor "anotherProperty". I cannot apply this solution to translate my query... am i mistaken? Thanks.

Comment: not exactly... the property name can be anything... i;ve edited my answer again... probably this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Right, this maybe is the solution. Thanks a lot. I cannot use it anyway because i need the query to execute in a sinble invokation to database. Nevertheless, i will suppose that there is not possible solution for this in Criteria and that i will have to do it in HSQL. I will take this as the correct answer if nothing better arises. BTW, i have opened a new question explaining the problem a bit more just in case you want to extend or comment something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346281/limitation-on-the-expressiveness-of-hibernate-criteria