# Limitation on the expressiveness of Hibernate (and JPA) Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have 4 entities in a Hierarchy like this:

```
               Parent
                  |
       ------------------------
       |          |           |
    Child1     Child2       Child3
```

And I am interested in retrieving All the instances of Child1 and Child2 (but not Child3 instances) with a criteria in a **single Query**.

This is easy to do with HQL (or JPQL) as follows:

```
FROM Parent obj  
WHERE obj IN (FROM Child1 where fieldOfChild1="aa") OR   
      obj IN (FROM Child2 where fieldOfChild2=55)
```

I have studied the Hibernate Criteria and JPA Criteria APIs and **I cannot find a way to express this query as a Criteria**.

**Is this a limitation of Criteria APIs**? or is it just that I missed the way? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an discriminator value for each subclass in your mapping (eg. 1 for Child1, 2 for Child2, 3 for Child3) you can use the special attribute "class" in your HQL/Criteria.

So a criteria query could be like this:

```
session.createCriteria(Parent.class)
       .add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("class", 1), 
                            Restrictions.eq("class", 2)))
```

And your HQL query simplified:

```
FROM parent WHERE class = 1 OR class = 2
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have such a discriminator. But anyway, the subqueries may do reference to other fields specific of the childs, i just simplified the problem... **I updated the question** to remark this.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you said that you haven't mapped your class hierarchy in your comment, have you?

So that a query for Child1 and Child2 can't be built with Criteria. In fact I don't think your HQL example works since Parent isn't mapped.

One ugly solution is to query to times, a Criteria query for Child1 and another Criteria query for Child2. And then merge both results lists in java code :(
Or map the hierarchy :)

Comment: Of course it works, Hibernate inspects the classes and discovers the Interface. I thought that Parent should be mapped as you, and I was also surprised when I saw that in fact it is not needed. For the 2 queries solution, I don't want to load in memory all that data and make 3 queries just because _Criteria is not powerful enough_. I prefer to do it in HQL. I just wanted to be sure that it was Criteria's fault, and not mine :). Anyways, even if i map the hierarchy, it wouldn't still work as I say in the comment of the other answer (I updated the question to reflect that situation). Thank you!!