# How to apply minus operation if only single query avaliable?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, math

I am building a search application where user can enter his criteria in the form to search . I am using an internal API to build the queries which is simmilar to Hibernate criteria building. I am supporting set operations among the selection criterias for better capability. now for minus on single query how should I build my criteria ?

For example

case 1: in a simple scenario user enters country, name and date of birth fields to search

select USER_ID 
from Table 1
where COUNTRY = "INDIA" AND NAME = "xyz" AND DATE_OF_BIRTH = "01/05/1990

case 2: now user want to search on multiple countries I am supporting sets, hence he will enter country as "US" in one set and and "UK" in other set. I will build a union query on them like

select USER_ID 
from Table 1 
where COUNTRY = "US" UNION select USER_ID from Table 1 where COUNTRY = "UK"

case 3: now user want user's from "US" but not "UK", then

select USER_ID 
 from Table 1 
 where COUNTRY = "US" MINUS select USER_ID from Table 1 where COUNTRY = "UK"

case 4: now If user want to negate his selection, like if he want all user's except from "Afganisthan" i.e if he want to perfrom minus operation on single set how should i build the query ?

case 5: now if user want to negate his selection , like if he want all user's except records satisyfying set 1, set 2 and set 3 conditions ?

update:

the use cases I have provided are simple cases but in reality I can have very complex queries. To support multiple db's, In query building our api supports only "AND", "OR" operators within query and "UNION", "INTERSECT" and "MINUS" among queries

Comment: for case 2: why not country in ('US','UK') and for case 3: why is the minus needed? could you pls explain?

Comment: I would like to know why you are doing an UNION instead of "where country='US' OR country='UK'"

Comment: `COUNTRY = "INDIA"` is most definitely not working as I doubt you have a column named `INDIA` in your table

Comment: @Hirak as i have updated our api not supporting in operator

Comment: I feel your pain. Please check this link... might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344701/hibernate-criteria-equivalent-for-in-clause-in-subqueries

Comment: Husman the example I have given is for understanding purpose, in reality there are various complicated operations I have to support. like to complicate the example If i want to search for user whose names starting with 'A' and ending with 'R' and belongs to either "US", "UK" , "CHINA", "JAPAN" and except date of birth in the range "01/05/1990" to "01/05/2008". I have to build the query from the form after user entering the criteria.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT USER_ID FROM TABLE 1 WHERE COUNTRY NOT IN "AFGHANISTAN"